# How to create an initrd image on OpenSuSE linux?

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, opensuse

```
/usr/src/linux-3.2.1 # make install
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
sh /usr/src/linux-3.2.1/arch/x86/boot/install.sh 3.2.1-12-desktop arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
                System.map "/boot"
You may need to create an initial ramdisk now.
```

--

```
/boot # mkinitrd initrd-3.2.1-12-desktop.img 3.2.1-12-desktop

Kernel image:   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.34-12-desktop
Initrd image:   /boot/initrd-2.6.34-12-desktop
Kernel Modules: <not available>
Could not find map initrd-3.2.1-12-desktop.img/boot/System.map, please specify a correct file with -M.
There was an error generating the initrd (9)
```

**See the error during mkinitrd command. What's the point that I am missing?**
What does this mean? `Kernel Modules: <not available>`

**OpenSuse 11.3 64 bit**

### EDIT1:

I did "make modules".
I copied the `System.map` file from the `/usr/src/linux-3.2.1` directory to `/boot`, now running `initrd` command gives the following error:

```
linux-dopx:/boot # mkinitrd initrd-3.2.1.img 3.2.1-desktop

Kernel image:   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.34-12-desktop
Initrd image:   /boot/initrd-2.6.34-12-desktop
Kernel Modules: <not available>
Could not find map initrd-3.2.1.img/boot/System.map, please specify a correct file with -M.

Kernel image:   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.1-12-desktop
Initrd image:   /boot/initrd-3.2.1-12-desktop
Kernel Modules: <not available>
Could not find map initrd-3.2.1.img/boot/System.map, please specify a correct file with -M.

Kernel image:   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.1-12-desktop.old
Initrd image:   /boot/initrd-3.2.1-12-desktop.old
Kernel Modules: <not available>
Could not find map initrd-3.2.1.img/boot/System.map, please specify a correct file with -M.
There was an error generating the initrd (9)
```

Comment: Which  distro?  
And the comment does say MAY, using Gentoo I don't bother with making an initrd, they're not *necessary*.

Comment: @bdowning sorry, have edited it. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using `mkinitramfs`, not `mkinitrd`.  The actual initrd format is obsolete and initramfs is used instead these days, even though it is still called an initrd.  Better yet, just use `update-initramfs`.  Also you need to run `make modules_install` to install the modules.

Comment: btw, I will carve out a seperate question for difference between initrd and initramfs, it will make a good Q&A :-)

Comment: `mkinitramfs` gives command not found on Suse.

Comment: @AnishaKaul, I guess Suse has a different tool for building it.  Debian based distributions use the initramfs-tools package.

Comment: ***SOLVED:*** The reason for these errors was that I was trying to make an initrd image before running `make modules_install`.

So, now I ran `make modules_install` and initrd image got automatically created in **/boot**.

Comment: ***CONCLUSION:*** On Kernel 3 onwards we don't have to create an initrd image, it gets created automatically after `make modules_install`.

Comment: @AnishaKaul, that is the expected behavior, as documented in the README file of the kernel sources.

Comment: @psusi openSUSE really uses `mkinitrd`. There is no `mkinitramfs`. I suse you talk about Debian based distro.

Answer (score 2):

With OpenSUSE, you can use

`yast2 sysconfig`

fill in 'INITRD_MODULES' with module you need and apply.